# How to copy text from the cmd console and keep the formatting (with color)?

Tags: windows, command-line, formatting

I want to cut and paste from cmd and **keep the color information** when pasting to another application. It's similar to pasting in most applications with formatting information.

Is there a way to do this? Or can it be done with an app similar to cmd?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The PowerShell folks, on [their blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/), posted an article titled: **[Colorized capture of console screen in HTML and RTF](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/colorized-capture-of-console-screen-in-html-and-rtf/)**

Once it's in a RTF file, with colors, open the RTF with Word or OpenOffice and copy the text to your target application.

As PowerShell is a nice replacement of cmd.exe with a lot more features, give it a try.

Comment: It's not so much a replacement as an alternative. Compatibility dictates that it can't replace cmd :-)

Comment: Yes, you're right, Johannes! "Danke schön" for the clarification :-) .

Comment: +Awesome! Thanks. It was a bit confusing at first since I had never used PowerShell, but it worked exactly as described.

Comment: There is a Gist with the code: https://gist.github.com/LeoColomb/1a683e7a05da067259e9

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

Windows Terminal can be handy with its `copyFormatting` setting (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/interaction).

Answer (score 1):

Snark's answer is useful, but the link is broken. The updated link to the MSDN blog post is here: [Colorized capture of console screen in HTML and RTF](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/colorized-capture-of-console-screen-in-html-and-rtf/)

You need to copy the functions from the blog post and then paste them into PowerShell. And then you can run commands like:

$htmlFileName = "$env:temp\ConsoleBuffer.html"
.\Get-ConsoleAsHtml | out-file $htmlFileName -encoding UTF8

Answer (score 0):

Colours in cmd are not the same as normal colours, it's the interpreter interpreting colour codes. I do not believe it's possible to do, and checking in Console2, it can't do it either, so it's probably for a very good reason.

Comment: AFAIK, Windows Console doesn't support ANSI colour codes (as Unix terminal emulators do); the program must call special functions to set the text colour. Also, a program can read the complete contents of its screen buffer (that's how that PowerShell snippet works) -- and it would be possible to make Console2 remember everything too. There's no real reason preventing it.

Comment: Well, I'm often wrong ;) I assumed the two would work similarly, as cygwin's tools have working colour, but they must have implemented that themselves.

Comment: @grawity looks like ansi is supported natively in windows console in windows 10 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a long winded way of doing it, using screen capture?

1. Hit Alt+PrtScr
2. This will copy the window to the clipboard
3. From Start, enter `mspaint`
4. Click on Edit/Paste or Ctrl-V to paste the contents of clipboard
5. Edit it to only show the command box and save it to PNG (GIF will lead to Paint dithering the classic grey text, and JPEG would create artefacts around your text).

Then those screen capture shots, will be ready to be inserted into Word as an image for documenting purposes. Of course, it's not text, so it won't be selectable. But it may be better than nothing.

Comment: The only thing this workaround is missing would be running OCR against the output image :) Overkill? Possibly, but probably easier to deal with than the accepted answer.